# How to interpret different lengths for the same unicode in python 3

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to understand the meaning of the different lengths I am getting for the same unicode character along with its bytes object !!!!!.

I know the first length (Len1) is the ACTUAL length of my single unicode charachter, the second length (Len2) might be the total number of bytes the single unicode char occupies, but what are the other remaining lengths (Len3 & Len4) represent ?. I am using python 3

```
MyStr = '✮'
print(MyStr," Len1 = ", len(MyStr))
print(bytes(MyStr, 'utf-8'), Len2 = ", len(bytes(MyStr, 'utf-8')))
print(MyStr.encode('unicode_escape'), " Len3 = ", len(MyStr.encode('unicode_escape')))
print(ascii(MyStr), " Len4 = ", len(ascii(MyStr)))
```

Here is the output ..

```
✮  Len1 =  1
b'\xe2\x9c\xae'  Len2 =  3
b'\\u272e'  Len3 =  6
'\u272e'  Len4 =  8
```

Comment: I think you should read this article by SO's co-founder: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses)

Comment: "the second length (Len2) might be the total number of bytes the single unicode char occupies", wrong, that is actually the lenght of the unicode sequence in bytes when represented as UTF-8. UTF-8 is just one of a number of ways of storing Unicode sequences (but nowadays an often used one).

Comment: @Anthon tbh you just reworded OP's assessment and added "as UTF-8".

Comment: @timgeb Honest about what? The OP used `utf-8` before I did, look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

How long the representation as bytes of a specific Unicode character is, depends on how you represent it, what the character is and if you count the quotes or not.

Your character "✮" needs three bytes to be represented as UTF-8 bytes stream. The more common '*' takes only one byte when represented as UTF-8.

Your other lengths are indicates of how long the string that represents the character is. Since the order of that character can be stored in a 16 bit value only 4 hexadecimals are needed, plus two positions for the escape `\u` makes a length of six.  If you make that into a string 2 extra positions for the quotes are counted.